# Фильтрация данных php

Tags: php, yii

Добрый день!
столкнулся с такой задачей:
на странице выводятся юзеры. Как сделать фильтр, чтобы можно было искать по countryid и по reg_date на этой странице?

контроллер.

```
public function actionUser()
    {
      $sql = "SELECT
                old_user.user_id,
                old_user.old_status,
                country.title,
                user.name,
                user.surname,
                user.avatar,
                user.country_id
                user.reg_date
                FROM
                old_user
                LEFT JOIN user ON old_user.user_id = user.id
                LEFT JOIN country ON user.country_id = country.id
                WHERE user.block = 0 AND user.avatar != ''
                ORDER BY user.reg_date DESC";

        $oldusers= Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
        $this->render('users', array('users' => $oldusers));
    }

view.php

foreach($users as $key=>$user) :?>
        <div class="man">
                <a class="ava-cf pull-left" href="/users/view/id/<?php echo $user['user_id']?>" style="height:140px;">
                    <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->params['static_url'].'big/'.$user['avatar'] ?>" width="140"  height="140">
                <div class="name"><a href="/users/view/id/<?php echo $user['user_id']?>" ><?php echo CHtml::encode($user['name'])?><br><?php echo CHtml::encode($user['surname'])?></a></div>
                <a class="country-flag" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->params['current_url']; ?>i/id/<?php echo $user['country_id']?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->params['static_url']; ?>/img/country/<?php echo $user['country_id'] ?>.png"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: @Rumata, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Вы, кажется, забыли про модель.  
Ответы для DAO- и AR-подходов будут разными.

Comment: хм, в моделях нет ничего (

Comment: @Rumata, я так тонко намекал, что в вашем MVC модели нет вообще. И вытяжка данных из БД... так себе.